# Clarification about matplotlib's base number/offset/scaling factor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to solve some randomly generated PDEs in python.

I have some graph outputs from some simulation code, and I have been wondering what specifically the number in the top left of matplotlib's display means. The reason is, I need to see a good fold change between peaks and troughs on the output.

I used the following line to change the scaling to a format I recognise (away from the 1e n format):

```
    plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0), useMathText=True)
```

This gives the following plot:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzzLy.png)

So my question is: Does the x10^63 mean that at x=0, y = 4*10^63? and likewise at x = ~10 y = ~0? (for the orange line).

My reason for asking is that I'm worried that this scaling behaviour is because the values are actually really close together and the wave patterns are due to numerical instability.

Really appreciate any guidance anyone can provide. Apologies if this is similar to any other questions asked, as you can probably tell I am not too familiar with the specific term for the number in the top left (in my head I have always called it a scaling factor), so I found it difficult to formulate a search for the answer to this question.

Comment: multiply all y labels by this scaling factor, i.e. `1.5` means `1.5*10^63`. (I don't know where you see `4*10^63` on your chart)

Comment: When the label at the top starts with a `+` sign, it would be an offset. An `x` indicates a scaling factor.